# Why do I get a error like "clang-9: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"?

Tags: c++, linker, clang, linker-errors, termux

I was working with basic c++ program in termux app. I changed the library headers from conio to curses(I have installed ncurses). 
But when I compile the code, it gives the output as a error. 
The code is,

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<curses.h>
    #include<iomanip>
    int main()
    {
    int area, length;
    std::cout<<"Enter the value";
    std::cin>>area;
    area=length*length;
    std::cout<<"area =" <<area<<std::endl;
    getch();
    }
```

Error is :

> clang-9: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: are you using the linker flag `-lncurses` while compiling?

Comment: Please find a better IDE. You won't get far with "*linker failed with exit code 1*" type of errors. You need to see the actual error(s) printed.

Comment: remove getch from your code.